# Преобразовать массив режима/график работы предприятия/магазина

Tags: php, массивы

Существует такой массив режима работы (примерно):

```
$shedule =
[
    "monday" => [
        "name" => "Понедельник",
        "name_short" => "Пн",
        "start" => "09:00",
        "end" => "21:00",
        "weekend" => "0",
    ],
    "tuesday" => [
        "name" => "Вторник",
        "name_short" => "Вт",
        "start" => "09:00",
        "end" => "21:00",
        "weekend" => "0",
    ],
    "wednesday" => [
        "name" => "Среда",
        "name_short" => "Ср",
        "start" => "09:00",
        "end" => "21:00",
        "weekend" => "0",
    ],
    "thursday" => [
        "name" => "Четверг",
        "name_short" => "Чт",
        "start" => "09:00",
        "end" => "21:00",
        "weekend" => "0",
    ],
    "friday" => [
        "name" => "Пятница",
        "name_short" => "Пт",
        "start" => "09:00",
        "end" => "21:00",
        "weekend" => "0",
    ],
    "saturday" => [
        "name" => "Суббота",
        "name_short" => "Сб",
        "start" => "10:00",
        "end" => "21:00",
        "weekend" => "0",
    ],
    "sunday" => [
        "name" => "Воскресенье",
        "name_short" => "Вс",
        "start" => "10:00",
        "end" => "21:00",
        "weekend" => "0",
    ],
];
```

С помощью PHP необходимо данный массив преобразовать в такой вид:
[image: Режим работы]

Плюс в каждом дне будет булевое значение выходного дня.

*Есть решение данного вопроса нижу, но оно **работает не совсем так** как нужно:* 
В данный момент оно не выводит последний день недели(Воскресенье) в связке с предыдущим добавленным днём (Пн-Вс, Сб-Вс).
Выводит просто `Сб` вместо `Сб-Вс` и так далее.

**Решение:**

```
function schedule($schedule)
    {
        $array = $array_equal = [];
        foreach ($schedule as $key => $value) {
            // Добавляем в массив первый день
            if ($key > 0) {
                // Сравниваем с предыдущим днём
                $diff = array_diff($value, $schedule[$key - 1]);
                // Два значения для сравнивания мы опускаем (сокращённое и полное название)
                // Если дни различаются, записываем в массив
                if (count($diff) > 2) {
                    // Записываем день в массив который будем выводить
                    $array[$key] = $value;
                    // Если отсуствует предыдущий день
                    if (!isset($array[$key - 1])) {
                        // Запускаем цикл пока не найдём последний записаный день в массиве
                        // Добавляем к названию последнего добавленного дня название предыдщуего дня
                        // Останавливаем цикл
                        for ($i=$key-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                            if (isset($array[$i])) {
                                $array[$i]['name_short'] .= '-' . $array_equal[$key - 1]['name_short'];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Массив одинаковых дней
                    $array_equal[$key] = $value;
                }
            } else {
                $array[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $array;
}
```

Comment: @РустамГимранов справделиво. Исправил. Ниже предоставил решение. Но оно не совсем правильно работает:
Если график воскресенья совпадает с предыдущим добавленным днём, то он не добавляет название воскресенья. Как-то так.

Comment: В массиве у вас воскресении по всей видимости ошибка `"weekend" => "0"`?

Comment: @РустамГимранов нет. С этим всё впорядке. Не выводится именно день воскресенья в связке с предыдущим добавленным днём. Например: Сб-Вс. Выводит просто Сб.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уверен, что коду необходим ревью. Если кому-нибудь понадобится, вот решение:

```
function schedule($schedule)
    {
        $array = $array_equal = [];
        foreach ($schedule as $key => $value) {
            // Добавляем в массив первый день
            if ($key > 0) {
                // Сравниваем с предыдущим днём
                $diff = array_diff($value, $schedule[$key - 1]);
                // Два значения для сравнивания мы опускаем (сокращённое и полное название)
                // Если дни различаются, записываем в массив
                if (count($diff) > 2) {
                    // Записываем день в массив который будем выводить
                    $array[$key] = $value;
                    // Если отсуствует предыдущий день
                    if (!isset($array[$key - 1])) {
                        // Запускаем цикл пока не найдём последний записаный день в массиве
                        // Добавляем к названию последнего добавленного дня название предыдщуего дня
                        // Останавливаем цикл
                        for ($i=$key-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                            if (isset($array[$i])) {
                                $array[$i]['name_short'] .= '-' . $array_equal[$key - 1]['name_short'];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Массив одинаковых дней
                    $array_equal[$key] = $value;
                }
            } else {
                $array[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $array;
```